# Regexp to match JSON key:value pairs with commas in value

Tags: json, regex, pcre

I have a JSON file having key:value pairs in this form:

```
{"key1":["value1","value2","value3",...],"key2":"value4","key":value5}
```

I would like to find a PCRE regexp able to capture KEY in **group1** and VALUE in **group2**. When there are multiple values I would like to capture all of them into **group2**.

In the example provided I would like to end up having these matches:

```
group1 --> key1
group2 --> "value1","value2","value3",...

group1 --> key2
group2 --> value4

group1 --> key3
group2 --> value5
```

Please note that when there are more than one value there is no limit at how many different values one can find and there are no line breaks that can help easily understand when we've reached the end of a KEY:VALUE pair.

Using `"(^")+":` I can easly isolate the KEYs but I'm not able to find a regexp able to capture the VALUEs.

Comment: Please invest some time into learning how to use a proper JSON _parser_.  Regex should only be against JSON once you have extracted perhaps a single scalar value.  Don't use regex to extract nested JSON content.

Comment: Looking at your top tags it seems you will want to use python's `json` module, the `jsoncpp` library or the `jq` linux executable

Comment: in case there's a [regex matching json in regex101 library](https://regex101.com/library/tA9pM8)

Comment: *It is not possible to get an arbitrary number of captures with a PCRE regex, as in case of repeated captures only the last captured value is stored in the group buffer.*